# Setting default value in SC.TableView

Tags: tableview, default-value, sproutcore

I am using SC.TableView. Picking the rows from a Record. But in one column I want to put some different strings which are not there in that Record.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you would need a seperate function for your content binding, that figures out in what line the content is set to something else. if you cant figure this out (my expertise here is limited as well), there is another idea:

you could use a little jquery hack, that just grabs this specific DOM element and changes its innerHTML.

hopefully someone else has a better idea

Comment: Actually I am not getting any attribute for the content of the cells. So not able to set it. :(

Comment: and have you tried the jquery work'around? something like "grab the fifth childDiv of the class xyz --> change inner html to something else"

Comment: Finally wrote diff function only..added the string in d json object which i was using as content of the table..working fine..thanks.. :)